# I'm using a class related to the Qtable widget but it doesn't show up in QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I can't show DataEntryForm class in App class, ie inside QMainWindow. thank you so much.

#QWidget,  The widget containing the QTableWidget I want to show

```
class DataEntryForm(QWidget):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.item = 0
        self.data = {"Phone L": 50.5}

        # leftside
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels('Descriptions', 'Price')
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table, 50)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

#QMainWindow,  I want to show the Data Entry Form class in this class.

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Hello, world!'
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(1200, 600)
        self.menuBar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('File')

        # export to csv file action
        exportAction = QAction('Export to csv', self)
        exportAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('data-analysis_icon-icons.com_52842.ico'))
        # exportAction.triggered.connect

        # exit Action
        exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exitAction.triggered.connect(lambda: app.quit())

        self.fileMenu.addAction(exportAction)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    x = DataEntryForm()
    ex = App(x)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMainWindow is a special type of QWidget that uses a [*central widget*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) that shows its main content. While you're correctly creating an instance of your `DataEntryForm`, you're just adding that as an argument in the main window constructor, but you're doing nothing with it.

In order to use that widget, use `setCentralWidget()`:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        # ...
```

<sub>Tip: avoid similar names for classes and instances of different types; `app` is an *instance* of a QApplication, `App` is a QMainWindow class. Use something different and more related for that class, like "MainWindow".</sub>